# Parallel processing a function that's in a separate module

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have what should be an "embarrasingly parallel" task: I'm trying to parse a number of log files in a CPU heavy manner. I don't care about the order they're done in, and the processes don't need to share any resources or threads.

I'm on a Windows machine.

My setup is something like:

*main.py*

```
import parse_file
import multiprocessing

...

files_list = ['c:\file1.log','c:\file2.log']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(None)

    for this_file in files_list:
        r = pool.apply_async(parse_file.parse, (this_file, parser_config))
        results = r.get()

...

#Code to do stuff with the results
```

`parse_file` is basically an entirely self-contained module that doesn't access any shared resources - the results are returned as a list.

This all runs absolutely fine when I ran it without multiprocessing, but when I enable it, what happens is that I get a huge wall of errors that indicate that the source module (the one that is in) is the one that's being run in parrallel. (The error is a database locking error for a something that is only in the source script (not the parse_file module), and at a point before the multiprocessing stuff!)

I don't pretend to understand the multiprocessing module, and worked from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884650/how-to-spawn-parallel-child-processes-on-a-multi-processor-system) examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533318/python-multiprocessing-pool-when-to-use-apply-apply-async-or-map) , but none of them include anything that indicates this is normal or why it's happening.

What am I doing wrong? How do I multi-process this task?
Thanks!

---

Easily replicable using this:
test.py

```
import multiprocessing
import test_victim

files_list = ['c:\file1.log','c:\file2.log']

print("Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(None)
    results = []
    for this_file in files_list:
        r = pool.map_async(test_victim.calculate, range(10), callback=results.append)
        results = r.get()

    print(results)
```

test_victim.py:

```
def calculate(value):
    return value * 10
```

The output when you run test.py should be:

```
Hello World
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

But in reality it is:

```
Hello World
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
Hello World
Hello World
```

(The actual number of extra "Hello World"s) changes every time I run it between 1 and 4 = there should be none)

Comment: Make sure the `for-loop` is indented so as to be inside the `if __name__ ...` statement. Otherwise the code will import-bomb on Windows.

Comment: @unutbu - Thanks. Per your suggestion I've just done that but it makes absolutely no difference I'm afraid. :-( (example updated to reflect this))

Comment: Please post the stack trace, at least the first few and last few lines.

Comment: In the stack trace, what is the last line that begins with `File` which refers to the path to your script (`main.py`)? and what is the line that follows it?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but it looks it to me like we would need to see the structure of how you are using sqlite3. A runnable example which reproduces the error would be terrific.

Comment: @unutbu - Simple reproducable case appended to the question. No SQLite necessary. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, when Python executes

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(None)
```

new Python processes are spawned. Because Windows does not have `os.fork`, these new Python processes re-import the calling module. Thus, anything not inside

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

gets executed once for each process spawned. That is why you are seeing multiple `Hello Worlds`.

Be sure to read the ["Safe importing of main module"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming) warning in the docs.

---

So to fix, put all the code that needs to run only once inside the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

statement.

---

For example, your runnable example would be fixed by placing

```
print("Hello World")
```

inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement:

```
import multiprocessing
import test_victim

files_list = ['c:\file1.log','c:\file2.log']

def main():
    print("Hello World")
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(None)
    results = []
    for this_file in files_list:
        r = pool.map_async(test_victim.calculate, range(10), callback=results.append)
        results = r.get()

    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

yields

```
Hello World
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

---

Especially on Windows, scripts that use `multiprocessing` must be both runnable (as a script) and importable. An easy way to make a script importable is to structure it as is shown above. Place everything that the *script* should execute inside a function called `main`, and then just use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

at the end of the script. The stuff before `main` should just be import statements and the definition of global constants.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried reading that document before posting this question, but it assumes a level of knowledge I simply don't have (i.e., it made no sense). main.py is too complex to add the __name__ thing to. so I created a separate file with just the multiprocessing stuff and am calling that from main.py but I still can't get it to work (anything inside the __name__ if doesn't get run *ever* - and if it's left out I get all manner of randomness). Can you provide an example with test.py please?

Comment: Thanks! In the end I just stuck `if __name__ == '__main__':` as the very first line of my main.py script. Everything is now ugly-indented but oh well. Thanks again.