# Spawn parallel processes for function and pass several different arguments to function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Hi everybody I took [Jiaaro's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/884753/2772305) as a template to convert it from threading to multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
from function_repo import run
from time import time

vitems = ['02','63','25','0']

num_processes = (multiprocessing.cpu_count()/1)
threads = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    begin = time()
    print begin
    # run until all the threads are done, and there is no data left
    while threads or vitems:
        if( len(threads) < (num_processes -1) ):

            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run,args=[vitems.pop()])

            p.start()

            print p, p.is_alive()

            threads.append(p)

        else:

            for thread in threads:

                if not thread.is_alive():

                    threads.remove(thread)
    print  'Hello, finished'
    print  'Took: ',(time()-begin)
```

It works nicely, but now I want to pass a second argument that is not a list to the `run` function, like `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run,args=([vitems.pop()],second_arg))`

This causes the function to break, because if I do so, the full list of `vitems` is passed to the function in  every single process.

How can i still only pass one item of `vitems` per process to the function  AND also pass a second non-list argument to the function `run` ?

thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=[vitems.pop()])` does not pass a list to `run`, it passes the item poped from `vitems` as the first argument. `args` is supposed to be a list/tuple of arguments passed to `run`.

To pass multiple arguments just do:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=(vitems.pop(), arg2, ...))
```